# jQuery multiple selectors - unrecognized expression

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to exclude some input and selects that wasn't selected any option from the form that going to be serialized, but I got error message that said my expresssion is unrecognized.
Here is JS:

```
$("#searchbtn").click(function () {
    var ser = $("form, select(:has(option[selected])), :input[id!='__VIEWSTATE'][value!='']").serialize();

    alert(ser);
});
```

P.S. I did updated JS code in order you do not confuse with these classes.

Comment: what is `.success` and `.error` you place them on wrong place

Comment: Guys, please do not pay attention to those success and error, definitely the prblem is not there.

Comment: Break it down into individual selectors and find out which one is causing the issue.

Comment: What is your jQuery version ?

Comment: @KevinLabécot version is 2.1.1

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/v539vp7s/2/

Comment: @Archer, yes, I can try this way, but I doubt about syntax - is everything is correct there?

Comment: Yes it's fine.  You can open the console on this page and run that code fine, which means it's something specific to your page.

Comment: is this `select(:has(option[selected]))` correct? wouldnt it be `select:has()`?

Comment: Seemed like Alex is right. Let me try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And final solution is:

```
var ser = $($("#ctl01")[0].elements).filter("select:has(option[selected]), input[id!='__VIEWSTATE']").serialize();
```

Comment: This select only elelemnts with option selected and exclude from serialize element with specific id.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra parenthesis in `select(:has(option[selected]))`, should be:

```
select:has(option[selected])
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/6ayvrrgx/)

Comment: Yes, select: really has problems with extra parenthesis. But what is strange now - i got value of input with id="__VIEWSTATE" that must be excluded from expression because it has id!=""

Comment: `input#__VIEWSTATE` isn't itself serialized, `form` element serialization includes `__VIEWSTATE=`  ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6ayvrrgx/1/))

Comment: No, viestate it's just same input with type=hidden, it's not some special kind of element when it rendered.

Comment: I think you're expecting the `:input[id!='__VIEWSTATE'][value!='']` selector to act as a filter for the `form` selector. This is not the case, the comma operator in the selector acts as an UNION. Your code serializes `input descendants of form` UNION `select that has selected option` UNION `inputs that match id!='__VIEWSTATE' and value!=''`.